# NullPointerException na hora de gerar gráfico

Tags: java, jfreechart

Estou criando um gráfico que puxa dados do banco, mas na hora de gerar o gráfico dá o seguinte erro:

**Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException**

A primeira linha que acusa no erro está dentro do método **createDataset** (é a primeira linha dentro do "**do**". Esse é o método:

```
private XYDataset createDataset(){
    XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Teste");
    conex.conectar();

    try{
    do{
        double rcv = conex.rs.getDouble("rcv_arena_verde"); 
        double rth = conex.rs.getDouble("rth_arena_verde"); 
    series.add(rcv, rth);

    } while (conex.rs.next());
    }catch (SQLException ex){ 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao preencher grafico \n " +ex.getMessage());
    }

    XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
    dataset.addSeries(series); 
    return dataset;
}
```

Os métodos/parametros de conexao com o banco estao corretos, afinal uso eles em outras classes no mesmo projeto e nao tenho problemas. Estou utilizando/chamando eles incorretamente? Tentei várias coisas e o erro persiste.

**EDIT**

Outras partes da classe para uma melhor compreensão da mesma:

```
public class GraficosArenaProceso extends javax.swing.JFrame {

ConexaoBanco conex = new ConexaoBanco();

ModeloBeansPruebasArenaEnVerde mod = new ModeloBeansPruebasArenaEnVerde();
DaoPruebasArenaEnVerde control = new DaoPruebasArenaEnVerde();


 public GraficosArenaProceso() {
    initComponents();
    initUI();
}

   private void initUI(){
    XYDataset dataset = createDataset();
    JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);

    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);

    // [...] Aspectos visuais do gráfico           

}
```

Método main:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        GraficosArenaProceso graficoProceso = new GraficosArenaProceso();
        graficoProceso.setVisible(true);
    } );
```

Comment: Observe que conex não é null, mas conex.rs sim. Este objeto talvez não tenha sido criado corretamente.

Comment: Realmente Fábio, o "conex.rs" nao foi inicializado. De que maneira devo fazer isso? Entendi o conceito por trás de ter que iniciar o conex.rs, afinal realmente está null, mas me perdi na forma correta de inicializar ele.

Answer (score 0):

Como colocado pelo @Fábio conex.rs é null. Veja o método que inicializa o objeto rs. 
Na mesma classe do private XYDataset createDataset(), veja se em algum momento o conex.rs é de fato inicializado.

Para um averiguação mais clara, compare com outros métodos desde o inicio até a chamada conex.rs.getDouble("rcv_arena_verde");

Se tu quiser mais ajuda, por favor compartilhe a classe toda.

Comment: Realmente me passou desapercebido e o "conex.rs" nao foi inicializado. Mas de que forma devo fazer isso? Confesso que nessa eu me perdi. Tenho um método "executaSQL" (está na classe de conexao com o banco e executa a query), teria alguma relacao? De todos modos editei o post principal com outras partes da classe e sigo tentando aqui. Abs!

Comment: Conseguiu inicializar? Qual era o problema?

Comment: Consegui, no método createDataset, abaixo de "conex.conectar()", coloquei meu método que executa queries conex.executaSQL(select...) e aí funcionou.